# Why does the Navier-Stokes energy equation neglect the pressure-volume work?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes

A strictly conservative form of the Navier-Stokes energy equation reads (Schlichting, Gersten: Boundary Layer Theory 2017, eq. 3.57)
$$\frac{\partial \rho e_t}{\partial t} + \mathrm{div}\left(\rho e_t \mathbf{u}\right) = \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot \mathbf{u}\right) - \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{q}\right) + Q$$
where $\rho$ is density, $e_t = e + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^T \cdot \mathbf{u} + \psi$ is the specific total energy, $e$ is the specific internal energy, $\mathbf{u}$ is the flow velocity, $\psi$ is the potential energy, $\mathbf{\sigma} = \mathbf{\tau} - p \mathrm{\mathbf{I}}$ is the Cauchy stress tensor, $\mathbf{\tau}$ is the viscous stress tensor, $p$ is the pressure, $\mathrm{\mathbf{I}}$ is the second-order identity tensor, $\mathbf{q}$ is the heat conduction vector and $Q$ is a point-like heat source.

In terms of total enthalpy $h_t = e_t + p/\rho$, this equation reads
$$\frac{\partial \rho h_t}{\partial t} + \mathrm{div}\left(\rho h_t \mathbf{u}\right) - \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} - \mathrm{div}\left(p \mathbf{u}\right) = \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot \mathbf{u}\right) - \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{q}\right) + Q$$
or (with $\mathbf{\sigma} = \mathbf{\tau} - p \mathrm{\mathbf{I}}$)
$$\frac{\partial \rho h_t}{\partial t} + \mathrm{div}\left(\rho h_t \mathbf{u}\right) - \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{\tau}\cdot \mathbf{u}\right) - \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{q}\right) + Q$$

I always thought total enthalpy was the sum of all energy forms that are connected to mass. Thus, total enthalpy can be transported/convected. So why is the pressure-volume work $pv = p/\rho$ not included? In my opinion, the energy equation should read
$$\frac{\partial \rho h_t}{\partial t} + \mathrm{div}\left(\rho h_t \mathbf{u}\right) = \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot \mathbf{u}\right) - \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{q}\right) + Q$$
Where is my error in reasoning? Even Bernoulli's equation for incompressible flow includes the term $p/\rho$.

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of all energy forms that are connected to mass"? Isn't this just the total energy $e_t$?

Comment: @Tofi This might by my error of reasoning. Why is the pressure-volume work not part of the energy that is stored with/inside the mass? Both (non-specific) internal energy $U$ and (non-specific) pressure-volume work $pV$ are extensive quantities. Thus, when I connect two previously separated volumes $V_1$ and $V_2$ to $V_3=V_1+V_2$, the resulting internal energy, pressure-volume work and enthalpy are $U_3=U_1+U_2$, $(pV)_3=(pV)_1+(pV)_2$ and $H_3=H_1+H_2$ respectively. Thus, the pressure-volume work is stored in there.

Comment: The equation you wrote in terms of enthalpy is the same as the original equation *minus* the Bernoulli equation (or more precisely minus the equation of motion contracted with the velocity vector).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/216366/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658078/226902