# Deriving the heat equation from compressible Navier Stokes equations

Tags: thermodynamics, navier-stokes

Starting from the **compressible Navier-Stokes equations**, I want to derive the standard form the **instationary heat equation**.

The **energy equation in general form** can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot \left(H\vec{v}\right)&=\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot\vec{v}-\vec{q}\right)
\end{align}
$$

or in a **more specific form**

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \left(\rho \epsilon + \frac{1}{2} \rho |\vec{v}|^2\right)}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \left(\left[ \rho \epsilon + \frac{1}{2} \rho |\vec{v}|^2 + p \right] \vec{v}  \right) = \dots \\
\dots \nabla \cdot \Bigg\langle \left( \eta \left[ \left( \nabla\otimes\vec{v} \right)^\top+\nabla\otimes\vec{v} \right]-\frac{2}{3}\eta \left(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\right)\mathbf{1}\right)\cdot\vec{v}+\lambda \nabla T \Bigg\rangle.
\end{align}
$$

Using the **caloric ideal EoS**

$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon=c_v T, \quad h=c_p T,\quad h=\epsilon + p/ \rho 
\end{align}
$$

we get

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \left(\rho c_{v} T + \frac{1}{2} \rho |\vec{v}|^2\right)}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \left(\left[ \rho c_{p} T + \frac{1}{2} \rho |\vec{v}|^2 \right] \vec{v}  \right) = \dots \\
\dots \nabla \cdot \Bigg\langle \left( \eta \left[ \left( \nabla\otimes\vec{v} \right)^\top+\nabla\otimes\vec{v} \right]-\frac{2}{3}\eta \left(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\right)\mathbf{1}\right)\cdot\vec{v}+\lambda \nabla T \Bigg\rangle.
\end{align}
$$

Now assuming

1. **Zero velocity**, $\vec{v}=0$,
2. **Zero viscosity**, $\eta=0$,

I end up with the following **heat equation**

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (\rho c_v T)}{\partial t} = \left( \lambda T_{x} \right)_{x}
                              + \left( \lambda T_{y} \right)_{y}
                              + \left( \lambda T_{z} \right)_{z},
\end{align}
$$

and not

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (\rho c_p T)}{\partial t} = \left( \lambda T_{x} \right)_{x}
                              + \left( \lambda T_{y} \right)_{y}
                              + \left( \lambda T_{z} \right)_{z}.
\end{align}
$$

as given in most literature, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation).

Any hints are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happened to the internal energy in the terms on the left side of the equation?

Comment: @ChetMiller I used the caloric ideal EoS and a universal thermodynamic relation: $\epsilon=c_v T, \quad h=c_p T,\quad h=\epsilon + p/ \rho$, see also my edit in the question.

Comment: So you're assuming an ideal gas, right?  Isn't the density a function of t?  If so, isn't v not equal to zero?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, I assume ideal gas, as stated in the question. I do not want to put a constraint on density. The density might or might not change during time, e.g., due to thermodynamic reasons or due to other external reasons. That's why I did not put it outside the time derivative.

Comment: Do you mean that $\vec{v}=0$ is inconsistent for time varying density? My main question is, why does the literature use a heat capacity with constant pressure.

Comment: If it is an ideal gas, then yes.  Isn't that what the continuity equation tells you?  You are aware that the enthalpy change of an ideal gas is always $dh-C_pdT$, assuming no chemical reaction, right?

Comment: @ChetMiller Sure, I am aware of that. We may also consider a constant density. However, how does this answer my question of either using $c_v$ or $c_p$. Currently I only do math. I do not see, what is wrong with the simplicfications.

Comment: @ChetMiller Moreover, I think it would be more consistent to use $c$
 instead of $c_p$ or $c_v$, especially if constant density is considered. Here, $c_p$
 and $c_v$ are meaningles. What's the reason literature uses $c_p$?

Comment: For an arbitrary material (solid, liquid, or gas), Cp is **defined** as$$C_p=\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}\right)_P$$So it is far from meaningless. And, $$C_v=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)_V$$

Comment: How can the density be constant if the temperature and/or pressure is changing?

Comment: @ChetMiller I am aware of that. The question is the other way around. The literature uses $c_p$ which means constant pressure. How is tempature allowed to change if density is constant?

Comment: I have no idea what you’re talking about

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. Can you give me a simple explanation, why the instationary heat equation uses $c_p$ instead of $c_v$? The simplification says $c_v$.

Comment: See Transport Phenomena by Bird, et al, Chapter 11 for correct mathematical handling of these quantities.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Pages 338 and 339 exactly point out, what I was trying to tell you. Also the case (iii) where $c \equiv c_p = c_v$ (see the footnotes) .

Comment: Good, so you got what you wanted.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658078/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251639/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/216366/226902

Comment: See also: "Derivation of continuum expression of the first law of thermodynamics" https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265026/226902

Comment: @Quillo Thank you for the reply. I think it is clear now, due to Chapter 11 of Bird et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quote Landau & Lifshitz: Fluid Mechanics, $\S 50$, page 188, $3^{rd}$ed:

> If the fluid velocity is small compared
> with the velocity of sound, the pressure variations occurring as a result of
> the motion are so small that the variation in the density (and in the other
> thermodynamic quantities) caused by them may be neglected. However, a
> non-uniformly heated fluid is still not completely incompressible in the
> sense used previously. The reason is that the density varies with the temperature;
> this variation cannot in general be neglected, and therefore, even
> at small velocities, the density of a non-uniformly heated fluid cannot be
> supposed constant. In determining the derivatives of thermodynamic
> quantities in this case, it is therefore necessary to suppose the pressure constant,
> and not the density.

From which it follows the use of $c_p$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate it.